# Why Isn't My Nested Div Inheriting The Parent Height?

Tags: inheritance, html, height, nested

I have a REALLY BASIC question regarding nested divs and height inheritance. Let's say I have the following html snippit:

```
...
<div style="height: 50px;">
    <div style="height: inherit;">
    </div>
</div>
...
```

I would think just by inspection that the inner div would have the same height (50px) as the outer one but when I tested it the height was not inherited.

First off, are parent/child relationships betwen divs defined by nesting one within the other? Next, what do I need to do to make the inner div inherit the outer one?

Sorry guys for such a basic question. I am running on fumes here been working (on something else for hours and I have to switch gears to this). Please don't bash me for asking such a dumb question. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are not able to `inherit` height of parent `div` use `height: 100%;` for `inner` div

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J6e8A/)

And btw your div does inherit height, it's just that if you want to see give it a `background-color` or a `border` and you'll see the inner div has inherited the height of it's parent div

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/J6e8A/2/)

Comment: Wow i feel dumb now. :) Thanks again.

Comment: @JanTacci yap, check out the demo

Comment: Dare I ask what _auto_ and _inherit_ mean? :)

Comment: @JanTacci your inner div does inherit height of your parent div, it's just that you've not specified any width to your div so you are not able to see, secondly inherit means it inherits the height of the outer container and if you use auto, it will increase it's height according to the content hope this helps you

Comment: So if I had specified a width to the inner _div_ then _inherit_ would have worked? Testing now. :)

Comment: @JanTacci no, it did inherited but you were not able to see it because width was not specified, wait I'll show you 1 more fiddle that will clear your, sorry I explained you in a lil wrong way, what I meant was if you want to see if your child div inherits the height just giv it a background color or a border and you'll be able to see http://jsfiddle.net/J6e8A/2/

Comment: I wish everyone were as nice as you especially to a person who asks dumb questions like me. :D

Comment: @JanTacci even I started all this asking dumb question, never mind :) happy coding

Comment: Jan Tacci, you should vote up Mr Alien's comments and his main answer and also hit the checkmark to accept his answer.  That's the main purpose of this site to help people with reputation be rewarded.